# IntelliJ isn't starting

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

I recoveried my computer than try to reınstall the Intellij but I could not. What can I do?

Comment: Hey, could you please translate the message in english + include the logs? It's hard to help you otherwise

Comment: things in image?

Answer (score 1):

The missing DLL is the one from [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685). Download the redistributable from Microsoft and install that first.